# Creating a "keyed record" to store inferred types

Tags: typescript

I have noticed that when you're building up run-time data structures, it's quite a trick to ensure that certain typed information is maintained. For instance, if you have two variables -- XXX and YYY -- and you put them into an array you will loose inference whereas within the object container below it is maintained:

```
const arrayContainer = [XXX, YYY];
const objContainer = { XXX, YYY };
```

This observation, lead me to realize that a data structure like what I'm calling `KeyedRecord` might be a useful way to pass along dynamic data structures that are not known at design time (aka, where you should just describe the type using TS).

````
/**
 * A "KeyedRecord" is intended to store a value without
 * losing any ability to infer type information later.
 *
 * The structure is always represented as a two-key
 * dictionary, where one key is always `__key` and the value
 * of this key points to the second key.
 *
 * For example:
 * ```ts
 * const song: KeyedRecord = { __key: "song", song: XXX }
 * ```
 */
export type KeyedRecord<
  T extends { __key: string } = { __key: string },
  U extends keyof T & "__key" = keyof T & "__key"
> = {
  [K in U]: T[K];
};
````

I've created a link to the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWhBaAiA0gUwJ5oCYCU0DGA9gE7ZLQCWAzlQHYAuad2O0DR01HJa0AhtABu-ADYBXPgHdKDABZFxDKLGiii1SnQDmAuhgEAjSqNkGO9AGZoS7DAAc+Wy6QC2-BpSJ01HmwDoVCBg4ABU5Pm4ScQIGcV4qWjEpfgxaXnteamYmbAEk9ikiAFoAa0wg6GxKWK86fhIMABpoKQiE7z5ygxoBURS06AADAH0R7qG9PPk+EQk0SqJLdjle7uh7Ii0GWgsZrkJvPO7AkMqAMVJoNAAPfld7UTQALkqh953K4jpuLm9tZ7QdBYPCHMjQAC80AA3tAxt1AUhqP8kC1kTpAQANbHQAC+b3eQWAUFumxIDDsjiBmBw+GIZAAPCpoKFrjcmCxaLD4ZhAVEtLpcZCYXDxryuAwSAK8U1mQBVNkc7C0bpLFnQABkyB5GAoUNVy1ZWqQOqQUAAfMLocyANooejQOUAXUBoTtToA3FBcV7IEA) too.

What I'd *like* to be able to do with this type is define the second *key* which holds the payload in such a way as to make the value *inferrable*. Inferences in TS are a beautiful thing but I am relatively new to this form of magic and seem to fail every time I pair a unary condition and the `infer` keyword together.

All I could come up with was:

```
export type KeyedRecord<
  N extends {} = {},
  T extends { __key: string } = { __key: string },
  U extends keyof T = keyof T & keyof N
> = {
  [K in U]: T[K];
};
```

I'm not even sure it adds any real value, it should work but it is quite explicit. I was hoping to not have to hang a generic off the type but provide the *guidance* for TS to just figure out how to infer the `song` value below:

```
const song: KeyedRecord<typeof XXX> = { __key: 'song', song: XXX };
```

I was thinking there must be some way to map the *value* of `__key` to the *key* which holds the payload but I came up short in my attempts so here I am asking for the wisdom of SO to help. I know this question is bit more abstract that many but hopefully some smart typescript god will find this an interesting question and enlighten the poor huddled masses (well ok ... "me").

Comment: Sorry - not really sure what you're asking here (without sounding rude!). I also don't understand how this helps with runtime types - typescript is purely compile time types, so not sure on the use case.

Comment: Is this what you're after - (pulling a value type by the key in __key)?https://tsplay.dev/Lw6gyN

Comment: @mbdavis when you use `typeof XXX` you are inferring run-time data structures into the type system. When you build API's being able to do this turns out to be very useful.

Comment: @mbdavis i am about to go for a run; will look again at your example when back but I suspect this would be lossy at first glance. If you know `io-ts` then this quick hack will give you a better idea of what I'm trying to preserve: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/GNlARm)

Comment: They're still compile time - typeof just allows you to create a type from a value. I'm still not sure what the question is from the playground - perhaps you could annotate with what you're expecting to happen?